$L^p$-norm of fractional laplacian of smooth cutoff

Suppose $\eta(x)$ is a smooth cutoff in $\mathbb{R}^N$ such that $\eta\equiv1$ for $|x|<\frac{r}2$,
$0\leq\eta\leq1$ for $|x|<r$ for some fixed $r>0$ and $\eta\equiv0$ in
$\mathbb{R}^N\setminus B_r(0)$. In other words, $\eta$ can be any compactly supported smooth function in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Then can we say that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|(-\Delta)^s\eta|^p\,dx<\infty$$ for all $p>1$? [Here $(-\Delta)^s$ denotes the fractional Laplacian for $0<s<1$.]

Only information I have that $(-\Delta)^s\eta\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$. But directly this can't be used since $\mathbb{R}^N$ is unbounded. Since $\eta$ is compactly supported, I think if $(-\Delta)^s\eta$ would be compactly supported as well, then it will be true.
I don't know if I am wrong somewhere. Any help is appreciated.

It’s not true that $(-\Delta)^s\eta$ has compact support, but it does decay at infinity.
First of all, we have the inequality $$ \vert (-\Delta)^s \eta(x) \vert \leq C \| \eta\|_{C^2(\mathbb R^n)}\tag{$\ast$} $$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$ with $C$ depending only on $n$ and $s$. Indeed, we have \begin{align*}
\vert (-\Delta )^s\eta(x) \vert &= \frac {c_{n,s}}2 \bigg \vert\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{2\eta(x)-\eta(x-y)-\eta(x+y)}{\vert y \vert^{n+2s}} \, dy \bigg \vert \\
&\leq C \bigg (\int_{B_1} \frac{\vert 2\eta(x)-\eta(x-y)-\eta(x+y)\vert }{\vert y \vert^{n+2s}} \, dy+ \int_{\mathbb R^n\setminus B_1 } \frac{\vert 2\eta(x)-\eta(x-y)-\eta(x+y)\vert }{\vert y \vert^{n+2s}} \, dy \bigg ) \\
&\leq C \bigg ( \| D^2\eta\|_{L^\infty(B_1(x))} \int_{B_1} \frac{dy}{\vert y \vert^{n+2s-2}} + 4 \| \eta\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)} \int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B_1} \frac{dy}{\vert y \vert^{n+2s}} \bigg )\\
&\leq C \| \eta\|_{C^2(\mathbb R^n)}.
\end{align*}
Hence, ($\ast$) implies $$ \|(-\Delta)^s\eta\|_{L^p(B_{2r})} \leq C \vert B_{2r}\vert \leq C$$ with $C$ depending on $n$, $s$ and $r$.
Now, for $x\in \mathbb R^n \setminus B_{2r}$, $\eta(x)=0$, so \begin{align*}
\vert (-\Delta)^s\eta(x)\vert &= c_{n,s}\bigg \vert \operatorname{P.V.}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{\eta(x)-\eta(y)}{\vert x - y \vert^{n+2s}}\,  \bigg \vert \\
&=c_{n,s}\int_{B_r}\frac{\eta(y)}{\vert x - y \vert^{n+2s}}\, dy\\
&\leq C \| \eta \|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)} \int_{B_r}\frac{dy}{\vert x - y \vert^{n+2s}}.
\end{align*} Then, for $y\in B_r$, $x\in \mathbb R^n\setminus B_{2r}$, we have $\vert y \vert \leq  r \leq \frac 12 \vert x \vert$, so  $$\vert x-y \vert \geq \vert x \vert - \vert y \vert \geq \frac 12 \vert x\vert . $$ Hence, \begin{align*}
\vert (-\Delta)^s\eta(x)\vert & \leq \frac{C \| \eta \|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}}{\vert x \vert^{n+2s}} \qquad \text{for all } x\in \mathbb R^n\setminus B_{2r} 
\end{align*} from which it follows, \begin{align*}
\| (-\Delta)^s\eta\|_{L^p(\mathbb R^n \setminus B_{2r})}&\leq C \| \eta \|_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)} \bigg (  \int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B_{2r}} \frac{dx}{\vert x \vert^{p(n+2s)}} \bigg )^{1/p}\leq C \| \eta \|_{C^2(\mathbb R^n)} .
\end{align*} Thus, $$\| (-\Delta)^s\eta\|_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)}\leq C\| \eta\|_{C^2(\mathbb R^n)} <+\infty$$ with $C$ depending only on $n$, $s$, $r$, and $p$.
